# Can not stop nohup process

Tags: process, nohup

I am trying to run a very complex statistical model that I expected to take a very long time, so I used `nohup` to run the process. However, I underestimated the length and it would take like 260+ days to complete so I want to cancel the process.

I attempted using  `ps aux |grep nohup` to get the PID, I get the following output:

```
 \<username> 4920  0.0  0.0  14224   972 pts/15   S+   01:53   0:00 grep nohup
```

When I use `kill -9 14224` I am told there is no process. So I used `ps -ef | grep beast-2` as I do not remember the entire command I entered. Pulls up the following:

```
144039      1  0 Jul22 pts/12   00:00:00 /bin/sh /opt/anaconda3/bin/beast-2 -seed 777 -working -overwrite -instances 3 -threads 3 -beagle_SSE /home/<username>/XML/ST736_MTBD1.xml
```

I use `kill -9 144039` and check again but the process is still running underneath a new PID.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process 14224 is the `grep nohup`, as `ps` told you. So, when you get your prompt back, the `grep` ended and therefore, it is logical that `kill` reports that there is no such process.

You will not see s process called `nohup` in your `ps` output.

So, how to find the process to kill?

As I don't have your `beast-2`, I will demonstrate with `nohup sleep 99 &`.

```
ps -ef | grep sleep
```

which would give me

```
ljm      1491988 1336776  0 16:43 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 999
ljm      1492021 1492069  0 16:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

1492021 is again my `grep`, so not important here. 1491988 is my nohupped `sleep`. The parent PID is 1336776. So checking it gives me

```
$ ps -f 1336776
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
ljm      1336776 1336769  0 Jul22 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
```

That is a `bash`. You can go-up even further, , for example using `pstree`:

```
$ pstree -ap  1336769
konsole,1336769
  └─bash,1336776
      └─sleep,1492051 999
```

So, if you kill the parent, it will no longer spawn new `beast-2`s. Here I would

```
kill 1336769
```

which kills the console and the `bash`, but not the nohupped sleep:

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
ljm      1492051       1  0 16:48 ?        00:00:00 sleep 999
ljm      1492285 1492069  0 16:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

The parent has now become `1`, which is the init process. If you kill the sleep now,

```
$ kill 1492051
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
ljm      1492329 1492069  0 16:59 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

then all is gone.

Comment: I think I understand. So then in my efforts I have accidentally killed the console and the bash after this post, so now there is nothing more I can do and now I have some computing resources that will always be used up until some Admin kills the process.

Comment: @MicroBiostat  Could you not just log in again as the same user? Kill does not depend on being in the same session as the runaway program.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant You are correct, I was mistaken. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was protecting laravel using nohup. I had to also kill the process bound to the port

use `fuser 8080/tcp` (change the port based on your own) and kill the PID found there.